# jQuery Ajax Error object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hvae a webmethod called using jquery ajax. I hits the error callback. Fine - I thought I will analyze the error - but it is coming as undefined.

What are the possibilities for the  error values to be undefined? How to fix this, if it is a trivial error?

Note: `xhr`,`status` and `error` are undefined.

Note:  I am using Chrome version 35 and IE 8

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function errorFunction(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        if (xhr == 'undefined' || xhr == undefined) {
            alert('undefined');
        } else {
            alert('object is there');
        }
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "admPlantParametersViewEdit.aspx/GetResult",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("success");
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: errorFunction()
    });
});
```

Comment: The question is too vague. What exactly is `undefined`?

Comment: @zerkm s - `xhr`,`status` and `error` are undefined. I am using Chrome version 35 and IE 8

Comment: Putting `()` after a function reference **always** calls the function. There is not magic involved here. You didn't put `()` after the `success` function either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the function so change this:

```
error: errorFunction()
```

to this:

```
error: errorFunction
```

When you put the parens there, you were actually calling the function immediately and passing it's return.  Without the parens, it is just a reference to the function that can be called later by the jQuery ajax infrastructure.

---

To further understand what was happening, your code `error: errorFunction()` was calling `errorFunction()` immediately with no arguments (which is what you were seeing in your debugging) and then fetching the return value from that function (which is `undefined`) and then putting that into your data structure which was passed to the ajax call.  So essentially, you were doing the equivalent of this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function errorFunction(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        if (xhr == 'undefined' || xhr == undefined) {
            alert('undefined');
        } else {
            alert('object is there');
        }
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }

    // obviously, not what you intended
    errorFunction();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "admPlantParametersViewEdit.aspx/GetResult",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("success");
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        // also not what you intended
        error: undefined
    });
});
```

---

If you aren't using `errorFunction()` in other places, then a more common way to do this is to define it inline like you did with the `success` handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "admPlantParametersViewEdit.aspx/GetResult",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("success");
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr);
            if (xhr == 'undefined' || xhr == undefined) {
                alert('undefined');
            } else {
                alert('object is there');
            }
            alert(status);
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```